# Enabled not working with plotOptions using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

It seem like a error.

Description:

There's already ''enabled'' used in the code but for some reason its not working. I am using a line chart with Highcharts and want the lines to be highlighted while fading out the others. Here is the code, do let me know what possibly can be the error.

```js
  const plotOptions = {
    series: {
      states: {
        inactive: {
          enabled: true,
          selected: true,
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Also there's a link below to the example which I am trying to achieve in my code.

How to reproduce
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-states-inactive-disabled

Some other similar examples :
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-selected/
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-select/

Answer (score 0):

In general, an inactive state is enabled by default.
Take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/64mopfyL/

In the code you provided, there is an option `inactive.selected` which in fact doesn't exist in Highcharts. Maybe you meant `line.selected` or `states.select`?

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states.select

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.selected

When it comes to the link you provided, the inactive state is set to false - that's why there is no highlighting when mouseover.

Perhaps you have another config options activated which affects this behaviour. In that case, please let me know, and I'll try to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have set enabled to true but still it doesn't work. I  am using Highcharts version 8.1.0 and I want the Highight feature to work with my code. Here is the dependencies I am using Please have a look into amd let me know is there anything I need to change.

Comment: "react": "^16.13.1",   "react-jsx-highcharts": "^4.1.0",
    "react-jsx-highstock": "^4.1.0", "highcharts": "^8.1.0",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.1.0", "typescript": "^4.0.2",

Comment: Hi! React-jsx-highcharts is the community wrapper and we don't provide official support for it. In that case, I would suggest contacting directly the wrapper author https://github.com/whawker/react-jsx-highcharts . 

You can also consider using our official react wrapper which is supported: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react .  Simplified demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-jb22w1